# What are some conditions that may cause fork() or system() calls to fail on Linux?

Tags: linux, process, system, fork

And how can one find out whether any of them are occuring, and leading to an error returned by fork() or system()?  In other words, if fork() or system() returns with an error, what are some things in Linux that I can check to diagnose why that particular error is happening?

For example:

- Just plain out of memory (results in errno ENOMEM) - check memory use with 'free' etc.
- Not enough memory for kernel to copy page tables and other accounting information of parent process (results in errno EAGAIN)
- Is there a global process limit? (results in errno EAGAIN also?)
- Is there a per-user process limit? How can I find out what it is?
- ...?

Comment: To clarify, when one knows that an error such as EAGAIN has occurred during fork() (errno == EAGAIN), how do you find out what specifically caused it (was it RLIMIT_NPROC? Was it an error copying page tables, or task scructure, and if so why? And how do you avoid it?)

Comment: I also asked a different, but related question about page tables in Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853736/how-to-find-or-calculate-a-linux-processs-page-table-size-and-other-kernel-accou

Answer (score 8):

> And how can one find out whether any of them are occuring?

Check the *errno* value if the result (return value) is -1

From the man page on Linux:

> RETURN VALUE
>    On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.
>
> ERRORS
>   EAGAIN
>   fork() cannot allocate sufficient memory to copy the parent's page tables and allocate a task structure for the child.
>   EAGAIN
>    It was not possible to create a new process because the caller's RLIMIT_NPROC resource limit was encountered. To exceed this limit, the process must have either the CAP_SYS_ADMIN or the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.
>   ENOMEM
>   fork() failed to allocate the necessary kernel structures because memory is tight.
>
> CONFORMING TO
>    SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.

Comment: The return value is -1, the errno variable is set to EAGAIN, ENOMEM, etc.

Comment: @Chas. Owens That's what I said. "Check the errno value IF the result is -1".

Comment: Ah, I parsed it as check the errno for -1, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my original comment.  I know all about the error codes (yes, I did read the man page before posting to stackoverflow! :), what I'm looking for is ways to find out conditions in the system led to those errors.  (Note, for one, that there are at least two conditions under which fork() sets EAGAIN.)

Comment: @Reed Hedges I guess you could check if the process limit has been exhausted and deduce from that if EAGAIN was set because of the limit or not.

Answer (score 1):

nproc in /etc/security/limits.conf can limit the number of processes per user.

You can check for failure by examining the return from fork.  A 0 means you are in the child, a positive number is the pid of the child and means you are in the parent, and a negative number means the fork failed.  When fork fails it sets the external variable errno.  You can use the functions in errno.h to examine it.  I normally just use perror to print the error (with some text prepended to it) to stderr.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("Could not fork: ");
        return 1;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("in child\n");
        return 0;
    };

    printf("in parent, child is %d\n", pid);

    return 0;
}
```