# How to find or calculate a Linux process's page table size and other kernel accounting?

Tags: linux, memory, process, operating-system

How can I find out how big a Linux process's page table is, along with any other variable-size process accounting?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question: Page table size , AFAIK, is not process dependant on the same platform (well . I may be wrong, I am not a linux guru ..) . Btw I wonder: do you really mean page *table* size ? Or do you mean instead the *page size*, as it is more more often needed by programmers IMHO ?

Comment: I mean the amount of (kernel) memory that a particular process's page table(s) are consuming.

Answer (score 8):

If you are really interested in the page tables, do a

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep PageTables
PageTables:      24496 kB
```

Comment: This is useful, but I need to find out whether this size is "too big".  If there is a limit to this size that would call fork() to fail, and how close to that limit is the kernel.  Ideally, I would also need to find out what portion of that PageTables size is being used by a specific process, such that when fork() tries to copy the tables for that process, the limit would be exceeded.

Answer (score 7):

Since Linux 2.6.10, the amount of memory used by a single process' page tables has been exposed via the VmPTE field of `/proc/<pid>/status`.

Comment: It seems to work well, except when I allocate huge pages with mmap: the size reported is a small constant, no matter the size of the allocation (kernel 4.4.0-77).

Comment: The value reported by the field VmPMD seems ok, it grows linearly with the size of the allocation, even with huge pages. But I don't think it accounts for the whole page table (the man says "Size of second-level page tables"). When experimenting with classical pages, this value is approximately 500 times lower than VmPTE.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Linux, but most UNIX variants provide [`sysctl(3)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&sektion=3) for this purpose. There is also the [`sysctl(8)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&sektion=8) command line utility.

Comment: What Unix allows you to read the pagetablesize (opposed to pagesize) via sysctl?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, back in Ye Olden Tymes, we used to call nlist(3) to get the system address for the data we were interested in, then open /dev/kmem, seek to the address, then read the data.  Not sure if this works in Linux, but it might be worth typing "man 3 nlist" and seeing what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You should describe your problem, and not ask about details. If you fork too much (especially with a process which has a large address space) there are all kind of things which go wrong (including out of memory), hitting a pagetable maximum size is IMHO not a realistic problem.

Thad said, I would also be interested to read a process pagetable share in Linux.

As a simple rule of thumb you can however asume that each process occopies a share in the pagetable which is equal to its virtual size, for example 6 bytes for each page. So for example if you have a Oracle Database with 8GB SGA and 500 Processes sharing it, each of the process will use 14MB pagetable, which results in 7GB pagetables+8GB SGA. (sample numbers from http://kevinclosson.wordpress.com/2009/07/25/little-things-doth-crabby-make-%E2%80%93-part-ix-sometimes-you-have-to-really-really-want-your-hugepages/)

Comment: Oh BTW, some numbers with Huge pages now:
http://kevinclosson.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/quantifying-hugepages-memory-savings-with-oracle-database-11g/