# fork and waitpid fail on linux. Without hitting the hard or soft limits

Tags: linux, perl, fork, out-of-memory

I have a process that must create and close threads on demand.

Each thread forks a new process using open2. Sometimes after executing the program for a long time open2 fails to fork the process sometimes and gives a "Can not allocate memory error", sometimes this happens for threads too.I know that the Linux has soft and hard limits but the number of the concurrent threads and processes for my server does not exceed those values.

Is there something like a counter for number of processes and threads that eliminates thread and process creation after sometime?

If it is so how servers like Postgres work for a long period of time?
The project has multiple processes that communicate using TCP, but the part that causes the error that i described in a frond end to mplayer, that is written in Perl. The code is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use IO::Select;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
use IPC::Open2;
use 5.010;
use Config;
BEGIN
{
    if(!$Config{useithreads})
    {
        die "Your perl does not compiled with threading support.";    
    }
}
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use constant
{
    SERVER_PORT=>5000,
    #Remote request packet fields
    PACKET_REQTYPE=>0,
    PACKET_FILENAM=>1,
    PACKET_VOLMLVL=>2,
    PACKET_ENDPOSI=>3,
    PACKET_SEEKPOS=>4,
    #our request typs
    PLAY_REQUEST=>1,
    STOP_REQUEST=>2,
    INFO_REQUEST=>3,
    VOCH_REQUEST=>4,
    PAUS_REQUEST=>5,
    PLPA_REQUEST=>6,
    SEEK_REQUEST=>7,
    #Play states
    STATE_PAUS=>0,
    STATE_PLAY=>1,
    STATE_STOP=>2,
};

#The following line must be added because of a bad behavior in the perl thread library that causes a SIGPIPE to be generated under heavy usage of the threads.
$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';
#This variable holds the server socket object
my $server_socket;
#This array is used to hold objects of our all threads
my @thread_objects;
#create the server socket
$server_socket=IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort=>SERVER_PORT,Listen=>20,Proto=>'tcp',Reuse=>1) or
die "Creating socket error ($@)";
#Now try to accept remote connections
print "Server socket created successfully now try to accept remote connections on port: ".SERVER_PORT."\n";
while(my $client_connection=$server_socket->accept())
{
    push @thread_objects,threads->create(\&player_thread,$client_connection);
    $thread_objects[$#thread_objects]->detach();
}



#This subroutine is used to play something using tcp-based commands
sub player_thread
{
    my $client_socket=shift;
    #create a new select object
    my $selector=IO::Select->new($client_socket);
    #this variabe is used to pars our request
    my @remote_request;
    #getting th thread id of the current thread
    my $tid=threads->self()->tid;
    #This variable is used to hold the pid of mplayer child
    my $mp_pid=-1;
    #Mplayer stdin and stdout file descriptors
    my ($MP_STDIN,$MP_STDOUT);
    #This variable is used to check if we are playing something now or not
    my $is_playing=STATE_STOP;


    print "Client thread $tid created.\n";
    while(1)
    {
        #check to see if we can read anything from our handler
        #print "Before select\n";
        #my @ready=$selector->can_read();
        #print "After select: @ready\n";
        #now the data is ready for reading so we read it here
        my $data=<$client_socket>;
        #This means if the connection is closed by the remote end
        if(!defined($data))
        {
            print "Remote connection has been closed in thread $tid mplayer id is: $mp_pid and state is: $is_playing.\n";
            #if we have an mplayer child when remote connection is closed we must wait for it
            #so that is work is done
            if($mp_pid!=-1 and $is_playing ==STATE_PLAY)
            {
                waitpid $mp_pid,0;
                $is_playing=STATE_STOP;
            }
            elsif($is_playing==STATE_PAUS and $mp_pid!=-1)
            {
                print "thread $tid is in the paused state, we must kill mplayer.\n";
                print $MP_STDIN "quit\n";
                waitpid $mp_pid,0;
                $is_playing=STATE_STOP;
            }
            last;
        }#if

        #FIXME:: Here we must validate our argument
        #Now we try to execute the command
        chomp($data);
        @remote_request=split ",",$data;
        print "@remote_request\n";

        #Trying to reap the death child and change the state of the thread
        my $dead_child=-1;
        $dead_child=&reaper($mp_pid);
        if($dead_child)
        {
            $is_playing=STATE_STOP;
            $mp_pid=-1;
        }

        given($remote_request[PACKET_REQTYPE])
        {
            when($_==PLAY_REQUEST)
            {
                print "Play request\n";
                if($is_playing==STATE_STOP)
                {
                    eval{$mp_pid=open2($MP_STDOUT,$MP_STDIN,"mplayer -slave -really-quiet -softvol -volume ".$remote_request[PACKET_VOLMLVL]." -endpos ".$remote_request[PACKET_ENDPOSI]." ./".$remote_request[PACKET_FILENAM]);};
                    print "Some error occurred in open2 system call: $@\n" if $@;
                    $is_playing=STATE_PLAY;
                    print "Mplayer pid: $mp_pid.\n";
                }
            }
            when($_==STOP_REQUEST)
            {
                print "Stop request\n";
                if($is_playing != STATE_STOP)
                {
                    print $MP_STDIN "pausing_keep stop\n";

                    #FIXME:: Maybe we should use WNOHANG here
                    my $id=waitpid $mp_pid,0;
                    print "Mplayer($id) stopped.\n";
                    $is_playing=STATE_STOP;
                    $mp_pid=-1;
                }
            }
            when($_==PAUS_REQUEST)
            {
                print "pause request\n";
                if($is_playing !=STATE_STOP)
                {
                    print $MP_STDIN "pausing_keep pause\n";
                    $is_playing=STATE_PAUS;
                }
            }
            when($_==VOCH_REQUEST)
            {
                print "volume change request\n";
                if($is_playing !=STATE_STOP)
                {
                    print $MP_STDIN "pausing_keep volume ".$remote_request[PACKET_VOLMLVL]." 1\n";
                }
            }
            when($_==INFO_REQUEST)
            {
                my $id;
                $id=&reaper($mp_pid);
                if($id > 0)
                {
                    print "Mplayer($id) stopped.\n";
                    $is_playing=STATE_STOP;
                    $mp_pid=-1;
                }

                given($is_playing)
                {
                    when($_==STATE_STOP)
                    {
                        print $client_socket "Stopped\n";
                    }
                    when($_==STATE_PAUS)
                    {
                        print $client_socket "Paused\n";
                    }
                    when($_==STATE_PLAY)
                    {
                        print $client_socket "Playing\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            when ($_==PLPA_REQUEST)
            {
                print "play paused request\n";
                if($is_playing==STATE_STOP)
                {
                    eval{$mp_pid=open2($MP_STDOUT,$MP_STDIN,"mplayer -slave -really-quiet -softvol -volume ".$remote_request[PACKET_VOLMLVL]." -endpos ".$remote_request[PACKET_ENDPOSI]." ./".$remote_request[PACKET_FILENAM]);};
                    print "Some error occurred in open2 system call: $@\n" if $@;
                    print $MP_STDIN "pausing_keep pause\n";
                    $is_playing=STATE_PAUS;
                }
            }
            when ($_==SEEK_REQUEST)
            {
                print "Seek request\n";
                if($is_playing != STATE_STOP)
                {
                    my $seek_pos=abs $remote_request[PACKET_SEEKPOS];
                    print $MP_STDIN "seek $seek_pos 2\n";
                    $is_playing=STATE_PLAY;
                }
            }
            default
            {
                warn "Invalid request($_)!!!";
                next;
            }
        }#Given

    }#while
    $client_socket->close();
    print "Thread $tid is exiting now, the child mplayer pid is: $mp_pid and state is: $is_playing.\n";
}
#The following subroutine takes a pid and if that pid is grater than 0 it tries to reap it
#if it is successful returns pid of the reaped process else 0
sub reaper
{
    my $pid=shift;
    if($pid > 0)
    {
        my $id=waitpid($pid,WNOHANG);
        if($id > 0)
        {
            return $id;               
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you show some code. Your question wording doubts the stability of the kernel, which is obviously not the issue. Showing the code will allow us to see the problem without relying on your understanding of it.

Comment: The code is not complete, but for testing it is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, it is because of a memory leak in the Perl's thread module that causes the memory to grow after a long time. Then open2 can not allocate memory and fails.

Answer (score 3):

`"Can not allocate memory error"` is what it says, either the user exceeded its memory quota (check with `ulimit -m`, compare to `ps ux`) or you're really out of memory (`free`).

The limits for max user processes are only indirectly connected - if you fork() more processes then the user's memory quota permits, fork() will fail with ENOMEM.

You also might want to see:
[What are some conditions that may cause fork() or system() calls to fail on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853725/what-are-some-conditions-that-may-cause-fork-or-system-calls-to-fail-on-linux)

Comment: I looked at ulimit -m, in the system it is set to 'unlimited'. As i described above i do not use fork directly, instead i use open2 call.

Comment: did you check that in the environment in which your perl script runs? if it daemonized, runs under screen, runs under at/cron, runs under env etc. it could have different parameters.

Comment: Yes, i checked them all, i used 'screen' command to run this under a Gentoo linux for about 24 hours. I had other processes too but only this one causes the problem.

Comment: As well did not used Cron or At to run this. It was execute manually in the screen.

Comment: As a sidenote, current linux kernels ignore ulimit -m completely.