# Fork fails with "resource temporarily unavailable". Which resource?

Tags: perl, fork, ulimit

I have inherited a Perl script that, depending on machine configuration, fails during calls to `fork` with `$? == 11`.

According to `errno.h` and [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853725/) [posts](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno), 11 is `EAGAIN`, i.e. "try again", because some resource was temporarily unavailable.

Is there a way to determine which resource caused the fork to fail,
other than  increasing various system limits one by one
([open file descriptors](https://serverfault.com/questions/374852/),
[swap space](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-swapspace.html), or
number of [allowable threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/))?

Comment: A forked process is a complete clone of the original process. Profiling your process before the fork will give you clue how much of each resources it is using.

Comment: Do you mean $!=11?

Comment: `Do you mean $!=11?`.  Actually, I misspoke somewhat.  What I should have said was that the fork is successful, but immediately ends with status code 11, as reported by `wait`.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with fork, so why did you accept my answer which is entirely about the errno set by fork on failure???

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean `$!` is `EAGAIN`, the `fork` man page on my system says:

> EAGAIN: fork() cannot allocate sufficient memory to copy the parent's page tables and allocate a task structure for the child.
>
> EAGAIN: It was not possible to create a new process because the caller's RLIMIT_NPROC resource limit was encountered.  To exceed this limit, the process must have either the CAP_SYS_ADMIN or the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.

Are you trying to create a ton of processes? Are you reaping your children when they are done?

Comment: See my comment above for a clarification of the original question, which was an over-simplification on my part.  The real sequence of events is as follows: after initialization, the program pre-processes a large (8Gb) file by means of some calls to system().   Then program forks one process for each cpu core on the machine.  So the program may be trying to duplication a very large memory space when it forks (but linux is copy-write, so that should be ok?).  There is a large amount of RAM (184Gb), and I raised the number of allowable open files and increased swap space.

Comment: Some of the forks succeed and some fail, and if I restrict the number of overall forks, then I can often get the program to run normally.

Comment: Re "*the fork is successful*", & "*Some of the forks succeed and some fail*", Which one is it? What call call is failiing? Why aren't you checking what error it's failing with?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the user has run out of free stacks.
Check the security configuration file on RHEL Server
`[root@server1 webapps]# cat /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`

`# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent`

`# accidental fork bombs.`

`# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.`

`*          soft    nproc     1024`

`root       soft    nproc     unlimited`

`[root@server1 webapps]# vi /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`

`[root@server1 webapps]#`

In my case, the "test" user was receiving the message "-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Resolved the issue by adding user specific limits for stack limit

`[root@server1 webapps]# vi/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`

`# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent`

`# accidental fork bombs.`

`# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.`

`*          soft    nproc     1024`

`test       soft    nproc     16384`

`root       soft    nproc     unlimited`

`[root@server1 webapps]#`